# Switch password visibility

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, textformfield

I am trying to hide password using this, but it is not working

```dart
 suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    controller.hidePassword.value =
                        !controller.hidePassword.value;
                  },
                  color: Theme.of(context).focusColor,
                  icon: Icon(controller.hidePassword.value
                      ? Icons.visibility_off_outlined
                      : Icons.visibility_outlined),
                ),
```

Comment: is `controller`==   `TextEditingController`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a `bool _showPassword` to handle password visibility.

Then use `TextFiled` inside `StatefullWidget` and use `setState` to have change effect on UI.

```dart
TextField(
              obscureText: _showPassword,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _showPassword = !_showPassword;
                    });
                  },
                  color: Theme.of(context).focusColor,
                  icon: Icon(
                    _showPassword
                        ? Icons.visibility_off_outlined
                        : Icons.visibility_outlined,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```